# How to make :wa overwrite externally-changed files?

Tags: save

I've noticed that when I have several files open in Vim, and one of the files has been changed by an external program, `:wa` doesn't actually try to write into that file. OTOH, going to that file and explicitly saying `:w` does try to actually write (I get asked whether I want to overwrite the changes).

I'd like `:wa` to behave like "for all files, do `:w`", so that I got asked whether I want to overwrite all the externally-changed files.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `:wa` you could try using [`:bufdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#:bufdo)`w`, which will issue `:w` for each buffer in the buffer list.

---

**Edit**:

Notice that the `bufdo` will change the buffer on the current window. The following command correct this and may also be easier to remember:

```
command! -nargs=0 Wa :bufdo w <bar> :edit #
```